# Infinite series with binomials and a hypergeometric function

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I've been struggling for days with *Mathematica* to sum this, but no luck, any ideas?

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-x)^j \sum_{r=0}^\infty (xw)^r \binom{k+2}{r} \binom{j+2r-4}{2k} \, {}_2F_1\left(-2k,-r ; 4-j-2r ; \frac{2}{w}\right)$$

No need to worry about convergence, consider $x$ and $w$ as *formal* parameters. I just want it in closed form and I have reasons to believe that it should exist and I expect it to be relatively simple.

Comment: A bit of context might help. I'm guessing you didn't come to this formulation by accident, after all....

Comment: The expression and my assumptions come from physics and I am absolutely certain that they would only distract from the simplicity of this problem – there are no additional constraints on any of the variables in question.

Comment: I mean, I'm a physicist by training, so I wouldn't mind that context. Moreover, the problem is hardly simple in its present form: You're summing over three integers with seemingly arbitrary hyperpgeometric function.

Comment: I appreciate your will to help, but it's a sub-problem in a sub-problem in a pages long research-level calculation, I'd have to backtrack a lot to explain it all and, believe me, it wouldn't add anything relevant :) Oh and I meant simple as in simple to state, of course it's not simple.

Comment: Have you tried to study this numerically for some fixed values of $x$ and $w$ for which triple sum exists? If so can you share them? I worry that you say "No need to worry about convergence". Seriously!

Comment: @JamesArathoon What I meant by *formal* parameters was that it is supposed to be a generating function. You really do not need to worry about convergence, seriously :)  I've been playing with some numerical results, but I'm afraid I've come up short of anything useful.

Comment: @lel I tried to do some numerical experiences with no success. If you have just some plausible vallues for x and w you might reduce the hypergeometric function to get more insight ? Did you investigate this way?

Comment: @lel for example (https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/02/0002/)

Comment: @lel means for w=2 and the reduction formular, we can perform one summation in Mathematica for further study.

Comment: It got too tedious for me to write out the coefficient of $x^u w^v$, though it is a finite sum, so working over $\mathbb{Q}[x, w^{\pm 1}]$ is indeed fine--sanity check passed. You might have better luck getting an answer if you write it out as $\sum_{u=0}^\infty \sum_{v=-\infty}^\infty c_{uv} x^u w^v$ where $c_{uv}$ is an explicit, finite double sum in terms of (say) falling factorials. The $w=1, 2$ cases may be instructive.

Comment: Upvote since you lost 350 rep